# Determine SQL Server version of linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Does anyone here know how i can determine the version of SQL running on my linked server through use of TSQL statements?

I am running SQL2005 my linked servers are running a mix of sql2000, 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select * from openquery(MyLinkedServer,'SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(''productversion'')')
```

Works

Comment: Correct, this does work perfect. Never thought of openquery.

Thanx

Answer (score 5):

One minor nitpick about OPENQUERY is that one cannot use anything other than string literals for both the server and the query.

With EXEC AT you can at least use varchar variables for the query (although it can be a pain to quote the stuff correctly) although not for the server-name:

declare @sql AS varchar(max) = 'SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(''productversion'')'
EXEC(@sql) AT MyLinkedServer

I assume this is just a parser limitation rather than some deliberate limitation in the design.

Comment: +1 because this answer is more versatile and can be used in a more flexible way when needed

Comment: I got so used to openquery, I didn't ever bother to try EXEC ... AT
This is way more flexible for calling server procs and parametrized queries. However, for simple things, openquery is more straight-forward.

Comment: This is the best solution. You've allowed ad hoc remote queries in your surface area if you can run OPENQUERY statements. That's a major security consideration, whereas Linked Servers can be explicitly controlled.

Comment: I got the error "Server 'MyLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC" when using exec () at MyLinkedServer, while the accepted answer works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can access @@version through a linked server using OPENQUERY

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(['+@servername+'],''select @@VERSION'')'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Returns a string detailing the version of the server.

Comment: @@Version does only work on the local server, not on the linked server

Comment: Same with SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try:

```
exec master..xp_msver
```